# Calling qsort on subset of array

Tags: c, struct, qsort

I have been looking for a way of sorting subset of arrays in C without moving the elements to a temporary array, and copying them back. I might have a bad understanding about qsort, but I think the below code should work:

```
qsort(&my_struct_arr[1],3,sizeof(my_struct),my_struct_cmp);
//my_struct_arr is a 4 element array, where i want to sort from position 1 to 3
int my_struct_cmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    my_struct A=*(my_struct*)a, B=*(my_struct*)b;
    if(A.x-B.x < 0.01) return A.y-B.y;
    return A.x-B.x;
}
typedef struct foo
{
    float x, y;
} my_struct;
```

Problem is, it does not work.

**Update 1:**
Okay, I see I wasn't entirely clear about the problem. I initalized the array from position 1 to 3, so I have an array with elements like this:

{ { ValueFromPreviousIteration.x,ValueFromPreviousIteration.y }, {x1,y1}, {x2,y2}, {x3,y3} }

My problem is, that qsort called like above will sort the entire array, whereas I only want to sort the last 3 elements of it.

Comment: You can make the problem even more clear by posting a small, complete, compilable example that demonstrates the problem. The `qsort()` call in what you've posted so far looks like it should do what you want (though the comparison function has problems as described in several answers).  So if the problem isn't the comparison, then it's likely something you haven't shown us.

Answer (score 1):

Your comparison function isn't stable. It can return different results depending on which order the structs are passed.

Consider the following struct values:

```
my_struct m = { -3.021, 30 };
my_struct n = { 3.010, 0 };    

int main(void)
{
    int comp1 = my_struct_cmp( &m, &n);
    int comp2 = my_struct_cmp( &n, &m);

    printf( "%d %d\n", comp1, comp2);

    return 0;
}
```

The first comparison indicates that `m > n`, while the second indicates that `n > m`. This kind of behavior confuses `qsort()`.

Comment: So, a call to `fabs()` is missing. **Furthermore,** it truncates the difference so if its absolute value is less than one, it will erroneously return 0 instead of `+/-1`.

Answer (score 0):

`int my_struct_cmp` returns int.

And you are returning `float`. It will be automatically converted to int, and probably `0`.

That's why it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Is `if(A.x-B.x < 0.01)` correct? You may want `if(A.x-B.x < 0.0)`. Use `0.0` instead of  `0.01`

Comment: I am doing this in an opengl program, where x and y represent coordinates. On the screen a difference of 0.01 in x makes no real difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to modify your compare function to something  like

```
int my_struct_cmp(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    const my_struct A = *(my_struct*)a, B = *(my_struct*)b;
    return fabs(A.x - B.x) >= 0.01 ? (A.x > B.x) - (A.x < B.x) : (A.y > B.y) - (A.y < B.y);
}
```

or (not so portable)

```
int my_struct_cmp(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    const my_struct A = *(my_struct*)a, B = *(my_struct*)b;
    return fabs(A.x - B.x) >= 0.01 ? copysign(1, A.x - B.x) : copysign(1, A.y - B.y);
}
```

otherwise, there exist many platform-specific solutions for determining sign of a float without performing comparisons, which is not a trivial matter, actually.

And this should be a bit faster:

```
int my_struct_cmp(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    const my_struct *A = (my_struct*)a, *B = (my_struct*)b;
    return fabs(A->x - B->x) >= 0.01 ? (A->x > B->x) - (A->x < B->x) : (A->y > B->y) - (A->y < B->y);
}
```